# Update the entire row after changing 1 column + Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have a observable array, with a list of values, every value has a percent calculated by :
`100 * valueQuantity / valuetotal`.

`valueQuantity = input value`
`valueTotal = value0 + value1 + value2`

If the user changes a value, the `valuetotal` needs to change and a recalculation has to be performed for the values (value0, value1 and value2) in the selected row.

I am using an extender to calculate the percent.

sample : [JS fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8vms5/63/)

I need to update the values after changing a value in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value you need in the calculation that can be changed needs to be a ko.observable in the model.
For example:

```
{ name: "CEP 7", value0: ko.observable(50), percent0: 0, value1: ko.observable(50), percent1: 0, value2: ko.observable(20), percent2: 0 },
```

Whichever value should be computed, should be a ko.computed value, not an observable.  For example:

```
percent0: ko.computed(function() {
    return this.value0() / (parseFloat(this.value0()) + parseFloat(this.value1()) + parseFloat(this.value2()));
}),
```

Then your binders should "just work".  Your use of declaring ko.observables in the markup seems unusual.

Comment: Come on :-) give it a shot first and I'll correct if need be.

Comment: I did but when setting ko.observable(50) it set the inputs to NaN

Comment: Good job.  I'd also recommend you move the ko.observable declaration out of the data-bind attribute like you have it, I edited my example to explain.